# <_io.TextIOWrapper name='input.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'> ошибка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
print(f)
f.close()
```

Выводит ТЕКСТ:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='input.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

(в самом файле два числа через пробел).

До этого, если не ошибаюсь(скорее всего ошибаюсь), так работало. В чем может быть причина ? если использовать `with open as`, тоже самое происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не ошибка. Вам выводит текстовое представление файлового объекта. Если вы хотите вывести содержимое файла, то надо его прочитать. Или вызовом соответствующего метода

```
print(f.read())
```

Или итерируя файловый объект

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

Comment: спасибо, заработала

Comment: @AnonChelovek [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).